# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. NodejS Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting this error

```
(index):1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/crm/addlead' from origin 'https://abc.examplehosting.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

i have added this code as well in my app.js

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
   

});
```

Please suggest what could be the issue.

Comment: allow this aswell `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
`

Comment: i did. still same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install `cors` [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

```
const cors = require('cors')

var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers like IE11
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Comment: having same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `cors` layer to your app,

```js
npm install --save cors

// In your server file
var cors = require('cors');
...

app.use(cors());
```

Find out more details on [cors here](https://medium.com/zero-equals-false/using-cors-in-express-cac7e29b005b#:%7E:text=and%20custom%20headers.-,Enabling%20CORS,using%20the%20cors%20npm%20module.&text=That%27s%20it.,CORS%20is%20now%20enabled.&text=The%20Access-Control-Allow-,allows%20access%20from%20any%20origin)

Comment: having same issue